# How to Color the Area Above the Curve in Gnuplot?

Tags: math, gnuplot, physics

I'm working on data visualization using Gnuplot and I would like to color the area above a curve similar to how it's shown in the following figure:

I would like to color the area above the curve with two different colors, cyan and red, as shown in the figure.

Could someone please advise me on how to achieve this in Gnuplot?

Thank you in advance for your help!

[image]

punto1=2.159070517372475, -2.150551183049983

punto2=9.999994158286656, 2.6135179349255238e-06

```
set xlabel  "Distance (Å)"   font ",25"
set ylabel  "Energy (eV)"  font ",25" 
set bmargin at screen 0.20
unset key
set border 15 lw 5
set tics font ",20"
unset grid
set xzeroaxis lw 3 
set format y "%.2f"
set grid
set xtics 1

set key vertical opaque r a

f(x) = -(2 * a * De) * exp(-a * (x - re)) * (1 - exp(-a * (x - re)))

De = 2.35   
a  = 1.82   
re = 1.77   


plot f(x) w l lw 3 lc "green" title "dV/dr"

set yrange [-5:7]
set xrange [0.5:10.5]

replot "punto1" w p pt 7 ps 1 lc "blue" notitle
replot "punto2" w p pt 7 ps 1 lc "blue" notitle

set style fill transparent solid 0.15 noborder

replot f(x) with filledcurves below x1=2 lc "purple" notitle

#filter(x,min,max) = (x > min && x < max) ? x : 1/0
#replot '+' using (filter(\$1, 1, 2.15)):(f(\$1)) with filledcurves above x1 lt 1 notitle 
set terminal pngcairo enhanced font 'Times New Roman,20' fontscale 1.5 size 1200,800
set output '$nombre.png'
set size ratio 0
rep
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion using an array. You need to know three x-coordinates:

1. first zero-crossing `x=1.77`, which is actually `re` (with your definition of `f(x)`)
2. (I assume) minimum of `f(x)` at `x=2.1590` and
3. end point `x=10`.

- there is no need for `replot`, you can do it all in one plot command
- `every ::1` plots the array only from the second value, check `help every`
- if you plot an array, column 2 is the value and `f($2)` is the function value at that x-value
- check `help arrays` and `help sampling 1D`

**Script:** (requires gnuplot>=5.2.0, because of the use of arrays)

```
### plot function with differently filled curve
reset session

f(x) = -(2 * a * De) * exp(-a * (x - re)) * (1 - exp(-a * (x - re)))
De = 2.35
a  = 1.82
re = 1.77

set xrange [0.5:10.5]
set yrange [-5:7]
set grid x,y
set xzeroaxis lw 3 
set key noautotitle
set samples 500

array P[3] = [re, 2.15907, 10.0]

plot sample [P[1]:P[2]] f(x) w filledcurves y=0 lc rgb 0xaaffff, \
            [P[2]:P[3]] f(x) w filledcurves y=0 lc rgb 0xffaaaa, \
     f(x) w l lw 3 lc "web-green" title "dV/dr", \
     P every ::1 u 2:(f($2)) w p pt 7 lc "black"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]